# Functional Gaussian Integral Involving Gradient Square with non-trivial Kernel

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, field-theory

I have been trying to solve the following functional gaussian integral. I've had problem finding the inverse kernel. $f(x)$ and $\rho(x)$ are two known scalar fields and they do vanish at infinity.

$\int \mathcal{D}\omega(x) \exp \bigl\{\int \mathrm{d}^3x\bigr[-\frac{\rho(x)}{2}|\nabla\omega(x)|^2 + f(x) \omega(x)\bigl]\bigl\}$

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.